# Meaning of: “I'll tell you something”

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In the TV show, *How I Met your Mother*, I can't understand what the following words in **bold type** means

> Barney: How long has it been? (without sex)
>
> Ted: Fifty seven days
>
> Barney: Fifty seven days!! Ted, you are in a slump.
>
> Ted: No it's not a slump. It's an intentional hiatus from girls. A slump is when you strike out every time you step up to the plate. But I'm off the roster, baby. I'm in the locker room sitting in the whirlpool and (**I'll tell you something**), it feels pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

As a form of emphasis. Similar might be "you would be surprised at how good it feels," but allows the extra punch of "good" at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Thank you so much..couldn't it be similar to seriously here?

Comment: Yeah similar, both might be used to repeat something the speaker has already said for example. I think "seriously" has more of a connotation that the speaker feels the listener might not be convinced, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a phrase indicating that the following bit is information you are pretty sure the other party either does not know or does not quite understand.

Comment: Thank you so much folks for your help....would you please make an example sentence to clarify it further?